# Euclidean geometry exercise

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I would like some help to solve this:

> Consider a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle A$ a right angle and
>   $BC=20$.  Divide $BC$ into four congruent segments, that is, take the
>   points $P,Q,R\in BC$ such that $BP=PQ=QR=RC=5$. Then, compute
>   $AP^2+AQ^2+AR^2$.

Thanks for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta_1=\angle APB$. By the Cosine Law,
$$AB^2=AP^2+25-2(AP)(5)\cos\theta_1.$$
Let $\theta_2=\angle APQ$. Note that $\cos\theta_2=-\cos\theta_1$, since $\theta_1+\theta_2=180^\circ$. So by the Cosine Law,
$$AQ^2=AP^2+25+2(AP)(5)\cos\theta_1.$$

Add up. We get 
$$AB^2+AQ^2=2AP^2+50.\tag{$1$}$$
Note the pretty cancellation!

We played a certain game at $P$. Play the same game at $R$.  We get 
$$AC^2+AQ^2=2AR^2+50.\tag{$2$}$$
Add $(1)$ and $(2)$, and use the Pythagorean Theorem. We get 
$400+2AQ^2=2AP^2+2AR^2+100$, and dividing by $2$,
$$AP^2+AR^2=AQ^2+150.$$

Play a **similar** game at $Q$, but using the double triangles $AQB$ and $AQC$. We get 
$$AB^2+AC^2=2AQ^2+200,$$ 
so $AQ^2=100$. (This calculation is more standard: it is how we obtain a formula for the length of a median, given the sides of a triangle.)

Thus $AP^2+AR^2=250$, and therefore $AP^2+AQ^2+AR^2=350$.

Comment: Nice! I will check if I have the Cosine Law at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

Hold the line $BC$ fixed and allow $A$ to move; it describes a circle of radius $10$ and centre $Q$, with $BC$ as a diameter. Extend $AQ$ to meet the other side of the circle at $S$; then $PARS$ is a parallelogram with centre at $Q$ whose diagonals have lengths $10$ (for $PR$) and $20$ (for $AS$). By the [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) we have $|AP|^2+|AR|^2=\frac12(10^2+20^2)=250$, and $|AQ|=10$, so the desired sum is $350$.

**Added:** Here’s a diagram that may help:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The parallelogram law can be proved without cosine law, right? I have to decide what solution is more elementary than the other one.

Comment: @Sigur: It can be proved [easily](http://www.unlvkappasigma.com/parallelogram_law/) using coordinates; synthetic proofs are possible but a good deal harder.

Answer (score 0):

Let points $S$, $T$ and $U$ be the feet of perpendiculars drawn from points $P$, $Q$ and $R$ to side $AB$ respectively.

$CP=PQ=QR=RB$ so $AS=ST=TU=UB$

Using the proportions produced by the similar triangles and the Pythagorean Theorem

$AB^2+AC^2=20^2\\
AP^2=AS^2+PS^2=\left(\displaystyle\frac{AB}4\right)^2+\left(\displaystyle\frac{3AC}4\right)^2\\
AQ^2=AT^2+QT^2=\left(\displaystyle\frac{AB}2\right)^2+\left(\displaystyle\frac{AC}2\right)^2\\
AR^2=AU^2+RU^2=\left(\displaystyle\frac{3AB}4\right)^2+\left(\displaystyle\frac{AC}4\right)^2$

Adding we find:

$AP^2+AQ^2+AR^2=\displaystyle\frac{14}{16}\left(AB^2+AC^2\right)=\displaystyle\frac78\times400=350$

Comment: Thank you for the comments.